# Equations export in PC and import in Mac show junk character

Tags: mac, microsoft-word-2010, desktop-computer, adobe-indesign, mathtype

I have been extracting equations from word files in a PC. Later, I use these equations in InDesign files using a Mac. While importing, I could find the variables/texts in the equations are changed to Junk Characters. I'm aware that because of font issue. My question is:

1. Is there any possibility to use a settings while exporting equations in PC that support MAC too.
2. Shall I apply InDesign fonts (book font) while exporting equations. Say, MS-word has Calibri font but my book uses Arial. (do not say to change in word file itself)

S/W: MS-word 2010, MathType, InDesign CS5.5

Comment: Think there are fully functioning office for Mac.

Comment: No, we use open office for Mac. That's why I convert them in PC and import in Mac

Comment: Pretty sure windows makes office for Mac, they do visual studio.

Comment: I understand if you want to use open source something or other but it is fact they make office and hence word for Mac. It probably can be subscribed monthly for like 9 dollars.

Comment: Thanks. Even then if I use office for Mac, how can I extract equations from word file using a particular setting.

Comment: Maybe something with excel? Or visual basic? It is good question. Also I do not know about "settings"